# How to group/join/merge overlapping UV islands

Tags: uv

I deliberately overlapped two UV-islands (on the screenshots) to texture them together and free some UV place, but when I unwrap the whole model (either via inner Blender algorithm or via uv packer addon) they unwrap separately and do not overlap.

[image]

[image]

How can I join/merge/group these two islands so they unwrap together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the faces you want to be overlapped, set a view in which they overlap (front orthographic in your example) and press U > Project from view.

In the UV editor select all and press P to Pin this unwrap (or go to menu > UV > Pin).

Select all and Unwrap the model: pinned vertices will stay in place.

Alt P to Unpin.

[image]