# Align UV islands according to 3D Space

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

My house model has many shingles but whenever I uv unwrap the model the islands are disorganized. In the 3d-viewport, if I were to select the polygons of the shingle in the upper corner, in UV space the selected island is located somewhere in the lower half of the grid. How do I organize the UV Islands in order according to the 3d-viewport [3d space][image: exhibit a]?

Comment: You can use "Project from view" UV unwrapping option. Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/287794/how-to-group-join-merge-overlapping-uv-islands/287800#287800

Comment: Both cube and project from view kinda works but now the polys in the uv editor are elongated in the wrong direction.  Do I need to reset the seems?

Comment: You can rotate UV by 90 degrees.